# Django: how to bind/save value from inline tinymce element to form field?

Tags: django, tinymce, django-crispy-forms

I have a crispy form with two fields: name and value.

I have to have inline tinymce editor on the value field.

So I did this to the form class:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('name', 'value')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm,, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'name',
            Field('value', type='hidden'),
            HTML('<div class="wrapper"><span class="editable"></span></div>'),
            FormAction(Submit('submit', 'Submit')
        )
```

in template:

```
{% crispy form %}

<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'span.editable',
    toolbar: "superscript subscript",
    menubar:false,
    inline:true
  });

$('span.editable').html($('#id_value').val());
```

What I can't figure out is how to save on form submit the edited span element text to the 'value' field.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right answer but it looks like it works for now...

I added submit event listener to the form and added new value from the span element to the hidden field.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#id_value').val($('span.editable').html());
});
```